# Css and js not loaded in Magento ver. 1.9.2.3

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, admin, javascript, css

Css and js not loaded in Magento ver. 1.9.2.3
[image: image admin panel]

Comment: Clear your cache

Comment: working on server fine but  localhost not working

Comment: clear cache folder

Comment: yes clear cache folder and check this link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62040/css-is-not-loading-on-the-frontend-in-magento

Comment: could also be the domain settings for the store in system -> config -> design (unsecure and secure skin/js urls)

Answer (score 3):

after seeing this its look like this is permission issue

reset permission by following command, fire below command in your magento root folder

```
chmod -R 644 ./*
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
chmod 550 ./mage
```

and also check skin url in your database `core_config_data` table

1) Login admin panel

2) go to `Sytem->Configuration->General->Web-> Unsecure`

3) change `Base Skin URL` to `{{unsecure_base_url}}skin/`

4) `Sytem->Configuration->General->Web-> Secure`

5) for this also `Base Skin URL` to `{{secure_base_url}}skin/`

6) go to `system->Cache Management` and Refresh the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you restored a database from a backup where **CSS and JS was merged**. If you can change the settings from admin panel then go to System->Developer->JavaScript Settings -> Merge JavaScript Files -> and set it to NO. Do the same for CSS settings. **If you cannot do it from admin panel** then run the sql

```
update core_config_data set value=0 where path ='dev/js/merge_files';

update core_config_data set value=0 where path ='dev/css/merge_css_files';
```

Dont forget to restart your apache (or) httpd service. Since, you are restarting one you can opt to restart mysql too.