# Magento 1.9 admin not loading properly

Tags: magento-1.9

I am having this issue the the admin panel is not loading properly. I don't know what the problem is.

[image]

Comment: it's seems like css and js not found.

Please check console and check css path

Comment: How do I check it??

Answer (score 0):

Probably want to clear cache firstly.  Then if it doesn't resolve check your file permissions.

refer to this answer:

[CSS is not loading on the frontend in Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62040/css-is-not-loading-on-the-frontend-in-magento)

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem i corrected this issue by changing url in fields

web/unsecure/base_url

web/secure/base_url

in table

PREFIX_core_config_data